# how to threshold between multiple range in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

I'm new to opencv and I'm using opencv2.4.5 with VS10C++ on windows7U(64bit). My project is to show an image after a threshold process between range 140 to 160, but I'm hangup for the last line

below is my code;

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    //open the video
VideoCapture cap2(argv[2]);
if ( !cap2.isOpened() )
    {
     cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

//Threshold value of 140 to 160
    if( cap2.isOpened() )
{
    Mat frame, frame_gray, result;

    for(;;)
    {
        int n;
        int t1=140, t2=160;
        n = 255;

        cap2>>frame;
        cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

        for (int i=0;i<frame_gray.size().height;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<frame_gray.size().width;j++)
            {
                uchar val;
                val = frame_gray.at<uchar>(j,i);
                if (val>t1 &&  val<t2) 
                    {val=255;}
                else 
                    {val=0;}

                frame_gray.at<uchar>(j,i)=val;
            }
```

How do I show the result after process loop multiple range threshold?

Comment: In the future, please post an example which compiles and runs when copy-pasted. Also, your thresholding code contains a bug which segfaults -- this is likely due to an indexing error while manually iterating over the image. Haris' suggestion to use `inRange()` is a much better, and less error-prone solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is [inRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) which will checks if array elements lie between the elements of two other arrays.

So change your code to

```
Mat thr;
inRange(frame_gray, Scalar(140),Scalar(160),thr);
imshow("processed",thr);
waitKey();
```